# XMPP 503 service-unavailable

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, xmppframework

I did some tinkering with my .cfg file, then put everything back to normal.

I can still connect then authenticate, but cannot register new users. Well, I have never been able to register users.

I'm using XMPPFramework for Obj-C with bridging from Swift to do something like this:

```
...
Static.xmppStream!.registerWithPassword("123", error: &error)
...
```

I don't think anything is wrong with the code, but it's something with the ejabberd server configuration.

I have:

```
{access, register, [{allow, all}]}.
```

and

```
{mod_register, [
    ...
    {access, register, [{allow, all}]}
```

in my configuration.

Comment: I have posted just now somewhat same question, it is actually ejabberd problem. I have tested with PSI desktop client and it did work flawless. But when i moved with webclient like JWChat then whenever i press login i see "Service is unavailable" ..
Check with JWChat web client first to see if its also your's ejabberd problem. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26969239/ejabberd-with-jwchat-is-not-working-service-is-unavailable

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. It does login at JWChat. However, it does login in the app too. It's just registration that does not work and I cannot test that in JWChat it seems.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up grabbing the cfg file from [here](https://github.com/astro/ejabberd/blob/master/src/ejabberd.cfg.example), and reconfiguring it.

Comment: Yes, your mod_register configuration was wrong and not referring to access model configuration name.

Answer (score 0):

mod_register should be like this:

```
  mod_register:
     access_from: allow
     access: all
```